# WP_User_Query orderby meta_val_num

Tags: wp-query, query, order, wp-user-query

I know that normal WP_Query's can have an `"orderby"` parameter of `"meta_value_num"`, but when I try to user `"orderby" => "meta_value_num"` on a WP_User_Query, it doesn't seem to work. Anyway I can obtain this functionality or is there something I'm missing?

Edit:

Here's what I've tried to retrieve results ordered by numeric meta values:

```
$sorted_users = new WP_User_Query(array(
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'satisfaction_rating',
    'order' => $order,
    'role' => 'subscriber',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'satisfaction_rating',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    )
));
```

Still doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but I believe if you set `type` in your meta query to `numeric`, that will cast the values as numbers so orderby `meta_value` should work correctly.

Comment: Please see my edit above. It doesn't seem to work but I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: You're not doing any sort of comparison, so it defaults to `=`, but you haven't set any value. If you just want to query on the user having that key with any value, you need to set `compare` to `EXISTS` in the meta query.

Comment: Alright. I'm kind of debating doing this all with a SQL query anyway as my code isn't very efficient at this point. I'm having a hard time finding where to start with the SQL query and I put another question up. I'll mark this answer as correct. Do you mind taking a look over at this question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179274/sql-query-equivalent-to-wp-query

Answer (score 0):

In WP_User_Query() you probably want to set orderly to 'meta_value_num' instead of 'meta_value' as well.

This is working with WP 4.7+.