# Searching user meta using WP_User_Query

Tags: wp-query, user-meta, wp-user-query

Per the documentation for WP_User_Query, there is an available search parameter. It looks something like this:

```
$users = new WP_User_Query(array(
    'search' => 'This is my search'
));
```

You can even set the columns in the database that are searched against using the "search_columns" parameter like so:

```
$users = new WP_User_Query(array(
    'search' => 'This is my search',
    'search_columns' => array( 'user_login', 'user_email' )
));
```

Now, the documentation mentions that you can modify the different columns available for search using the `user_search_columns` filter. That filter is defined on this page:

[Filter Reference/user search columns](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/user_search_columns)

I don't see anything about searching based on usermeta though. I want to add usermeta as a search column. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$yoursearchquery = 'This is my search';
$users = new WP_User_Query(array(
    'search' => $yoursearchquery,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'shoe_size',
            'value' => $yoursearchquery,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'shoe_color',
            'value' => $search_operation,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'shoe_maker',
            'value' => $yoursearchquery,
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
));
```

Comment: I have something similar to that currently, and I'm using a nested meta query. You cans my current query here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179274/sql-query-equivalent-to-wp-user-query?noredirect=1#comment261749_179274 It's under the edit in the main question. Problem is that it leads to duplicates being returned so I decided maybe the default search parameter would be better. If I can avoid duplicates I might be able to use meta query.

Comment: Also, small world :)

Comment: Duplicate as "same users returned twice"?

Comment: @Nathan I believe this results in a query where $yoursearchquery is searched in usermeta table among your different meta_key values with an `OR` relationship, but with an `AND` relationship when $yoursearchquery is searched in user table among the columns searched (by default or specified by `search_columns` arg.